# No matching signature for operator = for argument types: ARRAY<STRING>, STRING. Supported signature: ANY = ANY

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a bigquery repeated table on created_date, as in the image below

I am trying to do a simply WHERE query but receiving the error `No matching signature for operator = for argument types: ARRAY<STRING>, STRING. Supported signature: ANY = ANY`

[image]

Desired output:

just 2022-03-03T00:00:00,company_1, compapnu_1.com (without the 2nd row)

What is the correct way to query a repeated field?
My attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table` 
WHERE website = "company_1"
```

Answer (score 0):

An array needs to be unnested before comparing.

```sql
with tbl as (select "2022" date, ["comp1","comp2"] company_name union all select "2000",["test","comp1","comp1","comp1"])
select * 
from tbl
where (Select true from unnest(company_name) X where X = "comp1" limit 1)
```

or unnest the field direct to keep only these rows:

```sql
with tbl as (select "2022" date, ["comp1","comp2"] company_name, ["w1","w2"] as website union all select "2000",["test","comp1","comp1","comp1"],split("Wt w1 w2 w3 w4 w5", " "))
select * except(company_name,website),company_name_single
from tbl,
unnest(company_name) company_name_single with offset company_name_num,
unnest(website) website_single with offset website_num
where company_name_single = "comp1" and company_name_num=website_num
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but this still return the same result as in the image I shared. the desired output would NOT contain company_2; company_2.com